# Can't figure out why SAMLMessageSignature.Verify is returning false

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, shibboleth, component-space

I have setup Shibboleth as an IdP, using its default credentials (the certificates bundled with the installer).  I think it is using the idp-signing.crt certificate to sign SAML responses.  Using the LowLevelAPI ShibbolethSP example project, I have been able to login through the Shibboleth IdP, as long as I comment out the "Verify the response's signature" code.  I made sure I added in SHA-256 XML signature support in Global.asax.cs, Application_Start.  The message signature verification always returns false, even when I copy the idp-signing.crt file into the example directory and load that as a X509Certificate2 object, passing that in:

```
bool retVal = SAMLMessageSignature.Verify(samlResponseXml, x509Certificate);  // is false
```

It *even* returns false when I pass no second param in, using the key info included with the signature to perform the verification:

```
bool retVal = SAMLMessageSignature.Verify(samlResponseXml);  // is false
```

I can't figure out why this verification is failing.  Here is a SAML response that is posted back from Shibboleth (formatted by FOXE but otherwise unchanged):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response Destination="http://localhost:65231/SAML/AssertionConsumerService.aspx" ID="_b69dae7dd40119cff94ece076e338e82" InResponseTo="_031b0667-d6e5-4845-add1-f82748afe0e6" IssueInstant="2015-02-06T14:07:47.193Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:3380/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#_b69dae7dd40119cff94ece076e338e82">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>kL7hYIdYRk+x27VboYeYmIzOSfokmY8iPfucnFzI5Nk=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
V/bRv+kjvXcTOQs3d2TjyB4d0fjW5xSl5/8RJzCf1K988DsUWVqZEswxo4iqPVsjQgkelppbcnPa
9UTjLJLIQLg6ztXrfaXYE6iHZcYw58upBcnTXgNGuKazvLm6j2wxBtm5RNe8I4vO0YtDvV3GNf6X
qVICZlhp7VC0bNiCMr7zVXcw0E4ZfCSJt3Tph9MGKK6KrSXzVSpsyagtvBnmDx2CpI+O0hW92ekk
CjjkPcvY0lfl3rYdN/xpUqsJgc6HfhnBeU+y+RgEyb0eLuN/aZBOfiWMSAtMkJhcaoESwBtlaFg/
m46jdarT6ZDGfU9J4JnOzkAHlr8nMlEKcEzD8g==
</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDIDCCAgigAwIBAgIVANgMuf9G9xkZYBghdEkxjLMPwHJhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMBgxFjAU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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="_9d0be4db6f36fbd7026dc1efd7dfc224" IssueInstant="2015-02-06T14:07:47.193Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml2:Issuer>http://localhost:3380/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_9d0be4db6f36fbd7026dc1efd7dfc224">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>hR6KDOh+st3yunebqeUz4aqHMin/5rc6gHrkIwgypLc=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>
V9BB0UEBqsBGsiUHbVH8mw8sG52pLI6ec/lGMCqeNGqTUYF8HwOPpjkViJ/Pz91HRFIgRoPlVqHy
dRGMAJFpYvakOh/vB1+GP3T0Jh20gF8I7JfzOfMwuF8A5ryEdoxB6JQp0AR6mEXi88RPFfWrAmB1
G/mTt6Q94uW0lrqfiyphp49K6HNhRvyIOCOLWtthBdnMQPLlCh6NAMaJAh+2dzx2CjeT4P58H9FP
ANJQxB+JR3J2cum5XVn+Rrrx6fiL640I514G0dDu2bi4InXMGH/mKXVCLQX4w/1g0fGv/icrdY9H
734JhawjfY/+NfO4Fj3+E6Yx3+k8ytku0qUZkw==
</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDIDCCAgigAwIBAgIVANgMuf9G9xkZYBghdEkxjLMPwHJhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMBgxFjAU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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" NameQualifier="http://localhost:3380/idp/shibboleth" SPNameQualifier="http://localhost:65231/SAML/metadata.xml">AAdzZWNyZXQxpeMWTEyWX1tgYmk7ixdbi775mfBFBHikiub8dsf7HLwD2Xo5yPhD2HL21GF3Hle9oYEQCMFJ3R2dxZ8y22FknvLoGmDZ++VdymaQB0WpEaMzy3Ox9g8X6ALYMdZWedk78uCbpSvjpqdCM4Lhi13VdAQqvAs=</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData Address="127.0.0.1" InResponseTo="_031b0667-d6e5-4845-add1-f82748afe0e6" NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-06T14:12:47.236Z" Recipient="http://localhost:65231/SAML/AssertionConsumerService.aspx"/>
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2015-02-06T14:07:47.193Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-06T14:12:47.193Z">
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>http://localhost:65231/SAML/metadata.xml</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-02-06T14:07:47.057Z" SessionIndex="_267b5fd351054d45e5961e83427483fe">
            <saml2:SubjectLocality Address="127.0.0.1"/>
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
        <saml2:AttributeStatement>
            <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="username" Name="urn:ecolint.ch:attribute-def:username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml2:AttributeValue>Jeremy.Morton</saml2:AttributeValue>
            </saml2:Attribute>
        </saml2:AttributeStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Can anyone tell me why the Verify method might always be returning false?

Comment: put the literal response in a file (`response.xml`) and check the signature externally with `xmlsec1 verify --id-attr:ID "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol:Response" --pubkey-cert-pem idp-signing.crt response.xml` to make sure that you're using the right cert

Answer (score 0):

Assertions from Testshib are encrypted.
I use the low level api from component space. We are an SP for many clients and support numerous idP's

The SAMLResponse class has three methods I use testing the assertions from an idP.

First I try .GetAssertions(). 
If that doesn't return the assertions, I try .GetSignedAssertion(certificate).
If that doesn't return the assertion, I try .GetEncryptedAssertions()
The last is always where I get the assertions for Testshib.
Then, if you are using X509Certificate2, when you load your pfx file, you have to create that object with X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable. If not the private key will always be null.

I do something like this:

```
    var key = pfxCertificate.PrivateKey;

    if (key==null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("pfx private key is null");
    }

    foreach (var encryptedAssertion in encryptedAssertions)
    {
        assertions.Add(encryptedAssertion.Decrypt(key, null));
    }

    if (assertions.Count > 0)
    {
        samlAssertion = assertions[0];
    }
```

Finally, if you alter your SP metadata certificate you MUST upload it again to Testshib on their registration tab. The encrypted assertions use your certificate to encrypt. So, you use your private key to decrypt. If this doesn't match what was uploaded to Testshib, it will never decrypt. *Make sure the file name of your SP metadata is unique in the world, something like 
CrazyLikelyUniqueInTheWorld2939596.xml* Otherwise, someone else will overwrite your SP test metadata on Testshib if you name it something like spmetadata.xml